# How to sync firebase users across several locations? (extension + website)

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm working on chrome extension (provides main functionality) and the complementary website (mostly profile and billing related functionality) both backed with firebase backend.

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement the below scenario:

- user logs in with the extension using firebase authentication (with firebaseUI lib)
- I store a token that I can use to reauthenticate that user (is there such a token?)
- when user opens the website, I login that user automatically with the token.

While both the extension and the website has their login/signup forms I'm wondering if it's possible to login user in the extension and to somehow automatically login that same user on the website so they don't have to enter their credentials twice?

So far I was hoping that I could use something like below:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
            console.log("idToken = ", idToken)
})
```

And then to use that `idToken` like this, since if I understand correctly, it's an AWT:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(idToken).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     console.log("signInWithCustomToken: error = ", error)
 })
```

But it gives the following error:

```
code: "auth/invalid-custom-token"
message: "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."
```

I can parse the token on `https://jwt.io/` which shows all the user information but in the end it says "invalid signature"

So I guess this token can be only used to check authentication (like `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)`) but not to login user. Am I right?

I know I can create a custom token, but is there any straightforward way to workaround that and to login user from one place only using firebase funstionality? (of course without storing username/password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sign in with a Firebase ID token. What you can do is the following:

1. Keep the user session in the chrome extension and run all authenticated requests from there. Use `postMessage` (with origin verification) to talk with extension from app anytime a request is to be sent. With this you don't have to worry about session synchronization and no Firebase tokens are stored or passed to the web app or every web app that can access the extension.
2. Add a `postMessage` API to get an ID token from the extension after verifying the origin of the request. You can then send the request from the web app with the ID token. (less secure than 1 but easier to implement and session is stored in one place).
3. Create an HTTP endpoint that takes an ID token and returns a custom token. This would [`verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and then create a corresponding custom token for that user using [`createCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) provided by Admin SDK. You then `postMessage` that from chrome extension to the web page after verifying origin and [`signInWithCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) with that custom token in that web app. This is the least secure as you are providing an endpoint to exchange a short lived ID token with an indefinite session. You will also deal with synchronization issues (user signs out from chrome extension, you have to sign out from websites, etc).

Comment: thanks @bojeil, that all makes sense. Do I understand correctly that in the second case you've described there is no way to use firebase SDK but rather it's about creating own API (using firebase functions for example) to fetch the data?

Comment: And as for the third option - that looks to me similar to providing a "refresh token" functionality where user with a refresh token can obtain an access token at any time. This seems to be a widely used practice in OAuth (ex. gmail api with "offline" scope). I'm wondering why is that less secure and if it's secure "enough" to actually implement it?

Comment: In the second case, you need a `postMessage` protocol (client side only) to communicate between the extension and the web app. That is what I mean by `postMessage` API.

Comment: In the third case, you are increasing the window and points of attack. You will end up with a Firebase refresh token on the chrome extension and the web app. In addition, you are exposing an endpoint that can convert a short lived ID token to an indefinite session. An attacker who gets hold of an ID token can use this to sign in as the user. However, it is still safer than passing a refresh token directly since custom tokens and ID tokens have typically a 1 hour expiration.

Comment: thanks again @bojeil. Yes I understand about postMessage, my question was more about to confirm if I understand the flow where the app asks for the token from extension and then uses it on the web app side to send signed requests. This scenario implies sending of http requests to the firebase database hence there is no way to use firebase SDK (since it doesnt support http triggers) Is that right? As for the third option - how does that compares to gmail api (as example) in terms of security? To me both the scenario you've suggested and gmail token looks quite similar. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Do you need to use Firebase Database in your web app? You could use the REST API with an ID token but if that doesn't work for you, then you may need to consider something else. I am not sure what you mean by gmail API. From my understanding, all google API (calendar, drive, gmail, etc.), use OAuth based APIs where you pass access tokens to access their APIs. Not sure how the 3rd case is similar to that.

Comment: Yep, I'm using database but looks like this approach will require to move to REST API. Anyways, thanks for your clarification. As for google API, yes you are right it's bout OAuth and alongside with access token it's possible to also request a refresh token that enables you to generate an access token on demand - kind of "API to generate a custom token based on ID token" - in this case the ID token could be treated as a refresh token I guess - but this is just from security perspective if that makes sense. If I'm not missing anything, then this could be an appropriate way to proceed in my case