# How does Chrome Extension get user credential from Firebase web app without user having to sign in twice?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I have both a Firebase web app and a Chrome Extension - user will use Chrome Extension to save article that can be read later from their web app.

For web app, I use Firebase Auth. But I am unsure how to pass user token or id to Chrome Extension, so that user does not need to login twice.

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833658/how-to-communicate-firebase-webapp-with-chrome-extension-to-avoid-double-login?newreg=213b33cdfd804e28ad555baeda4fd1a0), but it is not clear to me how to send token to Chrome Extension from web app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a detailed answer with examples in [this github post](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/208#issuecomment-619418465)

Short scheme is following:

1. Create cloud function that generates custom firebase token
2. In web app upon login request a custom token from the cloud function
3. Using chrome API send message to extension
4. In extension on message use token to log into firebase
5. In extension listen to firebase auth state change to log out

Details from post:

### Firebase function / Auth Server

In a Firebase function (or a custom server) handle the token creation using firebase function `createCustomToken`

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

admin.initializeApp()

module.exports functions.https.onCall(uid =>
  admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
)
```

### Webapp

After a successful login, request the server for a custom Token passing the uid of the logged user

`firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createToken')(uid)`

Then send it to the chrome extension

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, token)`

### Extension

Finally in the extension when receiving a message, log the user with firebase using the custom token

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  console.log(
    'User state change detected from the Background script of the Chrome Extension:',
    user
  )
})

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  (token, sender, sendResponse) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCustomToken(token)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
      })
    return true
  }
)
```

Your background script will log the authStateChanged event where you can see that the auth is not isAnonymous anymore and the email attributes is the one of the user logged through your app !

Comment: This won't work without this setting https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/externally_connectable/